# Nativescript Sidekick Error: Cannot find suitable v8 version! Android Cloud Build

Tags: android, windows, build, nativescript

I try to build Android Nativescript App, with Sidekick, but always i get next error:

```
[20-05-06 18:46:17.245] (CLI) C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Desarrollo\NativeScript\xxxx\node_modules\nativescript-dev-webpack\snapshot\android\project-snapshot-generator.js:160
        throw new Error(noV8VersionFoundMessage);
        ^
Error: Cannot find suitable v8 version!
```

Only fail in Android build, build for iOS is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As error message say you don't have suitable java JDK.
You should download java 8 from here 
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

and select a suitable version for your operating system which is windows I think.
if you don't want to install it manually you can follow nativescript documentation and use this command :

```
choco install adoptopenjdk --version 8.192
```

useful documentation links :

https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win

https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/intro/installation

and make sure java is installed and registered by running

```
java -version
```

to check if java installed and add JAVA_HOME to environment variables and use

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

to check if JAVA_HOME variable is set as I show in the screenshot
[image]

Comment: C:\Users\XXXX>choco install adoptopenjdk --version 8.192
    Chocolatey v0.10.15

    Installing the following packages:
    adoptopenjdk
    By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
    adoptopenjdk v8.192 already installed.
    Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.

Comment: please make sure java is added to the path and add JAVA_HOME environment variable, I have updated the answer with more information.